# Hibernate + Map a list of Integer coming from a database function

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I try to define a Hibernate Entity that gets a list of calculated integers.
They are not stored in any table but calculated on the fly by database.

In my hibernate entity, I like to map this list to a List/Set.

> I try with `@Formula` like this

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
    ...
    @Formula(value = "database_fn_returning_id_list(col1, col2)")
    private Set<Integer> idList = new HashSet<>();
}
```

But it doesn't compile
`Could not determine type for java.util.Set, at table...`

> I also investigated with `@ElementCollection`

```
...
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable( name = "database_fn_returning_id_list(col1, col2)")
...
```

I get runtime error `Schema-validation: missing table [database_fn_returning_id_list(col1, col2)]`.
It seems to accept only existing tables.

Does somebody have an idea?

> **UPDATE**

After more research, it's seems than Hibernate don't map database array for following reason

- Not all DBMS support arrays. Because of that, Hibernate doesn’t support native database array types.
- Mappings as a @ElementCollection are not very efficient. Most developers prefer to model a many-to-many or one-to-many association.
- Hibernate can’t offer lazy-loading for the elements of an array. That makes it a bad data type for any associations.
- Possible to define custom `UserType` to support array of primitive types.

Source : [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-arrays-with-hibernate/) (Thorben Janssen) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hibernate-map-postgresql-array) (Baeldung)

Yet I fallback to a not great but working solution. All integer are concatenated into a string with separator.

When time and motivation will be available, I will dig into this `UserType`